How can i concatenate (dropzone.js) front chunk file with laravel controller
@section('css')
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/min/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

@endsection

@section('content')
<h1>File Upload Test</h1>
<form action="{{ route('examination.storeFile') }}" class="dropzone" id="file-upload" method="post">
    @csrf
</form>
@endsection

@section('js')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.9.3/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script>
   Dropzone.options.fileUpload = {
    paramName: "file",
    url: '{{ route("examination.storeFile") }}',
    maxFilesize: 1024, 
    chunking: true,6789
    
    chunkSize: 1048576, 
    retryChunks: true,
    retryChunksLimit: 3,
    acceptedFiles: '.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.pdf', 
    
    init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
           
        });
        this.on("error", function(file, response) {
           
            alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    }
};

</script>
@endsection


I WANT TO CHECK IN LOCAL disk  AND THEN I WANT TO UPLOAD IN AWS S3 , HOW CAN I CODE IN CONTROLLER  I DONT HAVE ANY IDEA TO MERGE CHUNK FILE , i dont have any idea how to do code in controller ?




Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
